# How to print a double with full precision on iOS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, double, precision, nslog

Test case:

```
NSLog(@"%f", M_PI);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", M_PI]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI]);
```

Results:

> 3.141593
>   3.141593
>   3.141592653589793

Conclusions:

1) Printing via NSLog() or [NSString stringWithFormat] provide a very low precision...

2) Printing via [NSNumber numberWithDouble] provides a better precision...

I would have expected to get a result much closer to the original value: 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288 (as defined in math.h)

Any clues?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first two lines round to 6 decimals because that's the default rounding length for `printf` inherited from C.

The third line displays the data with the maximum useful precision - an IEEE 754 64bit floating-point number has slightly less than 16 decimal digits of precision, so all those digits of the literal in `math.h` are pointless (perhaps they can be seen as future-proofing against a possible future redefinition in a format with more precision).

Answer (score 13):

You should use long double with a maximum formatting of 20 digits **@.20Lg**.
The long doubles are 80-bit floating points, so you will not get a better precision than that.
Be aware also that as of XCode 4.3.2 the constants are not in long double notation, even if the many digits suggest an uberlong double ;-)

```
NSLog(@"%.21g", M_PI);

// with cast because M_PI is not defined as long double
NSLog(@"%.21Lg", (long double)M_PI);

// with corrected long double representation (#.####L):
//                                   v from here on overhead 
NSLog(@"%.21Lg", 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288L);

// alternative for creating PI
NSLog(@"%.21Lg", asinl(1.0)*2.0);
// and a funny test case:
NSLog(@"%.21Lg", asinl(1.0)*2.0 - M_PI); // on second thought, not that funny: should be 0.0
```

the results are:

> ```
> p[5528:f803] 3.141592653589793116   (actually 16 digits standard double precision)
> p[5528:f803] 3.141592653589793116
> p[5528:f803] 3.14159265358979323851
> p[5528:f803] 3.14159265358979323851
> p[5575:f803] 1.22514845490862001043e-16 (should have been 0.0)
> ```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%.20f", M_PI);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not helping. The result is 3.14159265358979311600, which is badly rounded (the 5 last figures seem to be wrong)

Comment: @Ariel: that's because they are the result of rounding the true value to 52 binary digits and then converting the result back to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this work for me

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",distance]);

Answer (score -2):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI]);
```

a little more precision

Comment: Thanks, but it's not helping. The result is 3.141592653589793792, which is badly rounded (the 3 last figures seem to be wrong)