# How to convert NSDecimalNumber to CLLocationDegrees without losing precision?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I need to convert ***NSDecimalNumber*** with lat/lon values which I need to convert to ***CLLocationDegrees***. I used ***-[NSDecimalNumber doubleValue]*** method. But the value loses its precision. I want the values to be same. The following is what I am talking about(I hope everyone would be aware about this issue already).

```
NSString *coordStr = @"-33.890934125621094";
NSDecimalNumber *lat = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:coordStr];
NSLog(@"%@", lat); // -33.890934125621094
NSLog(@"%lf", [lat doubleValue]); // -33.890934
```

Is there any way that I should do instead of doing the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out to convert the String with the `doubleValue` method

```
NSString *coordStr = @"-33.890934125621094";

NSLog(@"%.17g",coordStr.doubleValue); //-33.890934125621094
```

Check out this post: [How to print a double with full precision on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729004/how-to-print-a-double-with-full-precision-on-ios)

**edit:**
the docu says:  `typedef double CLLocationDegrees;` so you can `double test = coordStr.doubleValue;` the problem is only, that `NSLog` doesn't print the complete value. but instead the double var saves the complete value.

Comment: Hm. Good. How to convert it to CLLocationDegrees?

Comment: docu says: typedef double CLLocationDegrees; so you can assign your double to your CLLocationDegrees var.

Comment: What I am asking is, the format specifier "%.17g" works with NSLog. How would you use it to assign it to a double variable?

Comment: double test = coordStr.doubleValue; the problem is only, that NSLog doesn't print the complete value. but instead the double var saves the complete value.

Comment: Man, Thanks a lot. I think I lost my mind. I've been foolish. Thanks for your help. Please update your answer with your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

CLLocationDegree is a double. So the maximum precision can only equal that of a double datatype.