# Xcode - NSTimeInterval Years double value, how to get MORE decimals?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimeinterval, decimal

i wan't to know exactly how many years it is between 2 NSDate's. (current Date and Date picker date)

i'm using NSTimeInterval (seconds) how to make it to years?

This code will make the value to Years:

```
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:date];

double secondsInAnYear = 31536000;
double YearsBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnYear;

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", YearsBetweenDates];

labelView.text = dateString;
```

but i just get 6 decimals!

i want more than 6 decimals. How?

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is a `typedef` for `double`.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729004/how-to-print-a-double-with-full-precision-on-ios

Comment: Thanks! it works! i'm using "%.20f" instead of "%f".

Comment: Is it possible to do: NSString *decimals =14; double x =3.1415926535897932384626433; label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%@f", x, decimals]; is this possible to get 14 decimals of x?

Comment: One way: `[NSString stringWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%@f", decimals], x]`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `-[NSCalendar (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags fromDate:(NSDate *)startingDate toDate:(NSDate *)resultDate options:(NSUInteger)opts]`. This does the calculation correctly. You can't assume a year always is exactly 31536000 seconds (leap year, or even those leap second(s) that get added occasionally).

Comment: This doesn't yield a decimal year. Only integers :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `%lf` which is the designated specifier for `long float`/`double` values?

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", YearsBetweenDate];
```