# Google Maps for iOS - How can you tell if a marker is within the bounds of the screen?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm trying to figure out a straightforward way to determine in Google Maps for iOS if a given GMSMarker is within the bounds of the visible map.  There seems to be solutions for this in the Javascript API but other than perhaps doing some complex reasoning based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317359/google-maps-ios-sdk-how-do-i-get-accurate-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-fr) there doesn't seem to be a way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Retrieve the bounds of your viewport with [GMSVisibleRegion](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/struct_g_m_s_visible_region) and create a [GMSCoordinateBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds) with it. Call [`containsCoordinate`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds#a88501beb137edd044e4dde9d1f73a0a5), passing in the marker's position. It should return true if the marker is within the viewport and false if not.

Answer (score 18):

A code example based on Andy's helpful response:

```
- (void)snapToMarkerIfItIsOutsideViewport:(GMSMarker *)m{
    GMSVisibleRegion region = _mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
    GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithRegion:region];
    if (![bounds containsCoordinate:m.position]){
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:m.position.latitude
                                              longitude:m.position.longitude
                                                   zoom:_mapView.camera.zoom];
        [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition: camera];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works perfectly! saves me a lot of time

Comment: What will it return if my marker is half inside the region and half is outside? Actually I want to check if my marker is fully inside the region or not. How can I check that?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, your marker is a point, so it doesn't have dimensions.  If your aim is to make sure that the graphic image you've associated with your marker is fully visible, I recommend iterating on this conditional, zooming out until it's satisfied, then zooming out one level more from that.

Answer (score 10):

The swift 4 version of the answer. Returning a boolean if marker is within the screen region or not

```
func isMarkerWithinScreen(marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    let region = self.mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: region)
    return bounds.contains(marker.position)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written on method to find  GMSMarker is in particular frame.
Set your rectangle frame (x,y,maxX,maxY). You can set any frame from screen it tell find marker is in that frame or not..

```
- (BOOL)isGoogleMapMarkerVisible:(GMSMarker*)marker {

    //Marker point
    CGPoint markerpoint = [self.mapview.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];

    //Maximum visible region from x and y axis
    float x = 0.0;
    float y = o.o;
    float maxX = self.mapview.frame.size.width;
    float maxY = self.mapview.frame.size.height;

    //If marker point is on visible region return true else return false
    if (markerpoint.x > x && markerpoint.y > y && markerpoint.x < maxX && markerpoint.y < maxY) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
            return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code may help to code hunters.

```
NSMutableArray *mutArrMarkers; //Have all markers added on Map
.
.
.
.

NSMutableArray *mutArrMarkersInPath = [NSMutableArray array];
[mutArrMarkers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
   GMSMarker *marker = obj;
   if(GMSGeometryContainsLocation(currentCoordinates, pathToCheck, YES)){
        [mutArrMarkersInPath addObject:marker];
   }
}];
```