# Find Inner most Polygon using actual Area from array of nested Polygon

Tags: ios, google-maps, cllocation, gmsmapview

I have Array of `GMSPath` and have Coordinate. I want to find out Path in which this Coordinate falls. I am able to find out total polygons in which this location falls. (Using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38826411/2225439) Everything is working fine up to this step.

The Actual issue comes when One closed `GMSPath` overlap with another Closed `GMSPath` and Coordinate is in overlapped area. As per my requirement, I have to get only one `GMSPath` out of these two and which have the smaller area than another.

***Please refer Image for better understanding.***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the area of `GMSPolygon` by using following method from Google Maps iOS SDK, `GMSGeometryArea()`, it provides area of given polygon. Now you have area, so you can compare different polygons and find innermost area.

```
double GMSGeometryArea(GMSPath *path);
```

As per description provided by google

```
Returns the area of a geodesic polygon defined by |path| on Earth.
The "inside" of the polygon is defined as not containing the South pole.
If |path| is not closed, it is implicitly treated as a closed path nevertheless and the result is the same.
All coordinates of the path must be valid.
If any segment of the path is a pair of antipodal points, the result is undefined -- because two antipodal points do not form a unique great circle segment on the sphere.
The polygon must be simple (not self-overlapping) and may be concave.
```

Comment: What units is the area in? I haven't been able to find anything that describes what unit of measurement `double GMSGeometryArea(GMSPath *path);` calculates.

Comment: The result are in square meters.