# Swift: How to know the top right and bottom left coordinates of a google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, bounding-box

I need to know the top right and bottom left coordinate in a google map each time the camera is moved. The API gives me the center point of the camera. Is there a way to get what I want with the API or with some algorithm knowing the center point(target), zoom and bearing?

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    position.target
    position.zoom
    position.bearing

}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3**

Use [GMSProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection)'s [visibleRegion](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/struct_g_m_s_visible_region) method.

```
let projection = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()

let topLeftCorner: CLLocationCoordinate2D = projection.farLeft
let topRightCorner: CLLocationCoordinate2D = projection.farRight
let bottomLeftCorner: CLLocationCoordinate2D = projection.nearLeft
let bottomRightCorner: CLLocationCoordinate2D = projection.nearRight
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317359/google-maps-ios-sdk-how-do-i-get-accurate-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-fr) too.

Answer (score 3):

How to know the top right and bottom left coordinates of a google map

Found this on [iOs Maps Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds)
`GMSCoordinateBounds` represents a rectangular bounding box on the Earth's surface. It has the northEast and southWest properties of the bounding box.

> - (id) initWithCoordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coord1 coordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coord2  Inits the northEast and southWest
>     bounds corresponding to the rectangular region defined by the two
>     corners. It is ambiguous whether the longitude of the box extends from
>     coord1 to coord2 or vice-versa;

Check this [Github repo](https://github.com/mariusfeldmann/MFGoogleMapAdditions/blob/master/GMSCoordinateBounds%2BGeometry.m) for additional info on how to use it in your code.

Comment: Actually I need to get those GMSCoordinateBounds from the mapView or the camera. But I can't find how to get them. There's a function to create a camera with bounds, but I don't need to create a camera, I need to get the bounds of the existing camera!